# Pressure and velocity in fluid dynamcis

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, velocity

I want to ask whether someone could help me solving a problem in understanding the relationship between pressure and velocity in fluid dynamics, please?

Why do I know that particles are not by accident equally moving, i.e. equal magnitude and equal direction? If this would happen, I end up with a problem in the relationship between pressure and fluid velocity. Say I would think about pressure being the transported momentum across the boundary of a fluid element. Then I have a problem, since I know that for equal pressure the fluid velocity should be zero. But if I think about a cloud of particles all moving with equal velocity the pressure in the given sense would be zero, i.e. constant, but obviously the velocity would not be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bernoulli equation addresses your question in the macroscopic sense; it is an energy balance for fluid in steady flow.  See a good thermodynamics book, such as one by Sonntag and Van Wylen, for an explanation of this equation; for example, how pressure can be reduced as velocity increases.

I defer to others for a microscopic level answer to your question.